# Roll up license counts for current accounts?

Tags: formula, roll-up-summary

having 2 issues with a similar blocker.

Currently when Opportunities are marked 'Closed Won', we require a 'Contract Start Date', 'Contract End Date', 'Paid Licenses', and other fields. We then have a formula that returns a true/false checkbox for 'Contract Active' (if the end date is > today())

At the Account level, I would like to summarize the number of 'Paid Licenses' from all closed won opportunities where 'Contract Active' = true, but I'm having trouble including the formula in roll-up summary? What's the best way to get around this?

I would also like to do the same thing for 'ARR' by summarizing all Closed Won opportunities 'Amount' where 'Contract Active' = True

Edit: I tried creating a flow that updates another field called 'Contract Active Update' to match the formula checkbox, but that doesn't seem to work either. No idea how to press forward.

EDIT 2: Here are images for the flow
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. We're not a code/config writing service. What you need to do is do some work on your own and then, if stuck, use [edit] to show where you are stuck

Comment: Of course - sorry if it came off that way. I edited the post to include what I've done so far and where I'm stuck. Genuinely don't know how to proceed forward.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5), you can't include formula fields if they have certain date functions like TODAY:

> Forbidden fields include formula fields containing functions that
> derive values on the fly, such as DATEVALUE, NOW, and TODAY.

Either you'll have to change your formula field to another kind of supported field and use automation to update the field value, or use a rollup app like Declarative Lookup Rollup Services (DLRS) or Rollup Helper.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic issue is that RSF will not work on formula fields that use TODAY() or NOW().  Formula fields are calculated when the record is queried so the passage of time by itself does not update the record - a prerequisite to entering the Save process that in turn includes the RSF calculation. See [Order of Execution](https://architect.salesforce.com/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png)

You are going to need a checkbox field that is *not a formula field* `Is_Contract_Active__c` that you set either

- In a Schedule-triggered Flow that runs every day looking at Opportunities that are not active
- In a record-triggered flow with scheduled paths that sets the field on end date + 1
- In a scheduled, batchable Apex job that runs every day lookiing at Opportunities that are not active

Once the new field is created, your RSF will work.

Comment: Hmm I tried creating a flow that triggers on Opportunity update and automatically sets a 'Contract Active Formula' field to be true or false based on 'Contract End Date'. But it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions on what I'm missing would be great

Comment: The Opportunity still has to undergo a Save event for the Flow to even be evaluated.  It is the passage of time that triggers the need to set the checkbox to true. Hence the three options I presented that use SFDC's inherent scheduling features